# Can you tell me why we use second argument is JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why we use second argument i.e Replacer in JSON.Stringify() like:

```
var a = {
b: 42,
c: "42",
d: [1,2,3]
};
JSON.stringify( a, ["b","c"] );
```

Comment: `If replacer is an array, the array's values indicate the names of the properties in the object that should be included in the resulting JSON string.` [`MDN reference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter)

Comment: You can find a very detailed page about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: From the documentation: [replacer, as an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Example_replacer_as_an_array)

Answer (score 0):

It serves as a whitelist for the JSON stringify function, as stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> A function that alters the behavior of the stringification process, or an array of String and Number objects that serve as a whitelist for selecting/filtering the properties of the value object to be included in the JSON string. If this value is null or not provided, all properties of the object are included in the resulting JSON string.